# What kind of events are accepted by Enzyme's simulate?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I know `simulate('click')` is used to test clicking on a component, but why is that instead of `simulate('onClick')`? And why does it take 'change' instead of 'onChange'?

'click' and 'change' aren't native html events. The docs say it just takes an ol' string.

```
   /**
     * Simulate events.
     * Returns itself.
     * @param args?
     */
    simulate(event: string, ...args: any[]): this;
```

Is there a list of type that is a source of truth for what kind of string the event parameter accepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.simulate()`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/57baba5ceaccec7a3ada40d7559f5bf71289cbe7/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1133) will call [`.simulateEvent()`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/57baba5ceaccec7a3ada40d7559f5bf71289cbe7/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16.3/src/ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js#L476) method, and `.simulateEvent()` will call [`propFromEvent()`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/57baba5ceaccec7a3ada40d7559f5bf71289cbe7/packages/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js#L86) function and it will call [`mapNativeEventNames()`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/57baba5ceaccec7a3ada40d7559f5bf71289cbe7/packages/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js#L16) to map browser native event name to react event camel-cased name without prefix `on`. E.g. `'touchstart'` will map to  `'touchStart'`.

Then, `propFromEvent()` will map the native event name to React element props event camel-cased name with prefix `on`. E.g. `'click' => 'onClick'`, `'mouseEnter' => 'onMouseEnter'`

So, `.simulate(event)` accepts browser native [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) type same with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It will help you map to React event props.

Full list of event types: [w3c](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-types-list)